# How t go at specific page in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this question have been answered before, but i have difficulty to pop on specific page in ios. As i have already tried many times. as i have  build 4 pages and and want to move last page to second page.
 with the help of this code i have gone through first page

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and with the help of this page i have gone to 3rd page.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but for second page i have written this code
but it's not working

```
ViewPage2 *ptwo=[[ViewPage2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewPage2" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:ptwo animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ViewPage2 *ptwo;

for (UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[ViewPage2 class]]) {
        
        ptwo = (ViewPage2 *)vc;
        break;
    }
}

[self.navigationController popToViewController:ptwo animated:true];
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you create new view controller which is not in the stack. What you should do is following:

```
for (UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if ( [vc isKindOfClass:ViewPage2]){
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:true];
        return; //optional
    }
}
```

Comment: ViewPage2 is, but you have to be aware that your first line will initalize new one, and that one in particular is not there. You have to find exact view controller to which you want to push. You can check this with memory adresses as well - You will see that your new ViewPage2 will have different memory adress then the one in navigation stack

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    
    //Do not forget to import YourViewController.h
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]]) {
        
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                              animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this

first import the ViewController on which page u want to go.
like

```
#import ViewController.h
```

Then u can do the following

instantiate the class

```
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc ] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

or you can do `popToViewController` too

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple answer:

```
     NSArray *arr = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
                         [self.navigationController popToViewController:[arr objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

In place of,

```
[arr objectAtIndex:0]
```

here you can give index of specified view controller that you need to pop.